# How to load imports automatically in cabal repl?

Tags: haskell, cabal, ghci

I am under the impression that until recently `cabal repl` automatically imported all the imports from the currently loaded file. That is if I had a file `src/Main.hs`:

```
module Main where

import qualified Data.Vector as V

main = putStrLn "foo"
```

And I would load it in `cabal repl` with `:l src/Main.hs`, `V` would be available without any further work.

I believe this behavior changed during the change to ghc/ghci `7.10`, but I am not sure. Is there any option that would let me change that back to the way it was before?

**edit:** As it happens I have actually compiled the modules, which was part of the problem. See *Ørjan Johansens* comment below.

Comment: This behavior isn't changed with 7.10, are you sure you're not having any errors while loading? In that case you may not have imports available.

Comment: The behavior you want only happens for *interpreted* modules. If a loaded module is compiled, you only get access to what it exports. To quote [the User's Guide](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/7.10.2/docs/html/users_guide/interactive-evaluation.html#ghci-load-scope): "To ensure that GHCi loads the interpreted version of a module, add the `*` when loading the module, e.g. `:load *M`."

Comment: If it was errors, then to reduce the annoyingness of (at least type) errors while loading, I recommend the `-fdefer-type-errors` option.

Comment: @ØrjanJohansen I actually have compiled the modules. Loading with the `*` solves this problem. If you just write that down as an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [GHC User's Guide](https://downloads.haskell.org/%7Eghc/7.10.2/docs/html/users_guide/interactive-evaluation.html#ghci-load-scope):

> The syntax in the prompt `*module` indicates that it is the full top-level scope of module that is contributing to the scope for expressions typed at the prompt. Without the `*`, just the exports of the module are visible.
>
> NOTE: for technical reasons, GHCi can only support the `*`-form for modules that are interpreted. Compiled modules and package modules can only contribute their exports to the current scope. To ensure that GHCi loads the interpreted version of a module, add the `*` when loading the module, e.g. `:load *M`.

In other words, add a `*` before the module name when loading.